# dc.js render bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I'm trying to render a bar chart using the dc.js library.
My csv dataset is formatted like so:

> q, year, category, subcategory, total, 
>   q1, 2010, x, xa, 200 
>   q2, 2010, y, yb, 100 
>   q3, 2010, x, xa, 300 
>   q4, 2010, z, zb, 45 
>   q1, 2010, x, xa, 80 
>   q2, 2010, y, yb, 200 
>   q3, 2010, x, xc, 301 
>   q4, 2010, z, za, 205 
>   q1, 2011, x, xa, 80 
>   q2, 2011, y, yb, 200 
>   q3, 2011, x, xc, 301 
>   q4, 2011, z, za, 205

So far, I'm able to get a bar chart, but the actual data isn't rendered to the chart, also the scaling on the x-axis is off as well, since it should be according to years. I'm having difficulty appending the data to the graph. This is all that I've been able to get

[image]

I'm loading in the data through d3.csv as follows:

```
d3.csv("records.csv", function(csv) {
    var data = crossfilter(csv);

    var fiscalyear = data.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.year;
    });

    var spendGroup = fiscalyear.group().reduce(
        function(p,v) {
            return p.total += v.total;
        },
        function(p,v) {
            return p.total -= v.total;
        },
        function() {
            return  {totalSpend:0};
        }
    );

fiscalyearchart.width(600)
    .height(300)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 60})
    .dimension(fiscalyear)
    .group(spendGroup)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([2010,2013]))
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .centerBar(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .brushOn(true);

    dc.renderAll();

});
```

Comment: what result you want ?

Comment: i'm looking to get the total pull per quarter per year in the bar chart.. so should be about 4 bars per year interval

Comment: can you give sample chart image or example

Comment: see this http://plnkr.co/edit/X5bDDDEr6GHvm7CmXSGe?p=preview is it useful for you ?

Comment: makes sense, but i'm trying to apply the dc.js library to the dataset, pivoting the data around a quarter dimension within a fiscal year dimension. the graph is the end result that i'm looking for, but not in the way that i want it to be rendered/drafted up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default `valueAccessor` determines the height of each column on Y axis. By default it assumes you it can use the value returned by your crossfilter group. So it expects something like:

```
console.log(group.all())

// [{key: 2010, value: 1},
//  {key: 2011, value: 2}]
```

But instead you are using a custom reduce function returning an object.

Your objects will look like this:

```
console.log(group.all())

// [{key: 2010, value: {total:NaN, totalSpend:0}},
//  {key: 2011, value: {total:NaN, totalSpend:0}}]
```

DC doesn't know what do with values like: `{total:NaN, totalSpend:0}`. You need to pass a valueAccessor to extract a numeric value like

```
chart.valueAccessor(function(d) {return d.totalSpend;});
```

Also, I presume you have a typo and really want to use `p.totalSpend` rather than `p.total`. But you could simplify further by just doing:

```
var spendGroup = fiscalyear.group().reduce(
    function(p,v) {
        return p += v.total;
    },
    function(p,v) {
        return p -= v.total;
    },
    function() {
        return 0;
    }
);
```

And this will return a `.valueAccessor` function dc can understand without customization. Even easier though, crossfilter already has a convenience function for this:

```
var spendGroup = fiscalyear.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.total;});
```

And DC has utility to create the callback:

```
var spendGroup = fiscalyear.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck('total'));
```

Comment: thanks! I was able to get the chart rendered and grouped according to quarter within a fiscal year :)